# lightgbm how to deal with No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf

Tags: lightgbm

how to deal with  [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
is there any parameters not suit?

Answer (score 12):

Some explanation from lightGBM's issues:

> it means the learning of tree in current iteration should be stop, due to cannot split any more.
>
> I think this is caused by "min_data_in_leaf":1000, you can set it to a smaller value.
>
> This is not a bug, it is a feature.
>
> The output message is to warn user that your parameters may be wrong, or your dataset is not easy to learn.

link: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/640

So on the contrary, the data is hard to fit.

Comment: Reducing 'num_leaves' helps to avoid using an unnecessary number of leaves on top of what is helpful. Reducing this value helps to avoid the warning message.

Answer (score 6):

This means that no improvement can be gained by adding additional leaves to the tree subject to the restrictions of the hyperparameters. It is not necessarily a bad thing, as limiting the depth of the tree can prevent overfitting. However, if the tree is underfitting the data, try tweaking these hyperparameters:

- decrease `min_data_in_leaf` - minimum number of data points in a leaf
- decrease `min_sum_hessian_in_leaf` - Minimum sum of the Hessian (second derivative of the objective function evaluated for each observation) for observations in a leaf. For some regression objectives, this is just the minimum number of records that have to fall into each node. For classification objectives, it represents a sum over a distribution of probabilities. It works like [min_child_weight in xgboost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317073/explanation-of-min-child-weight-in-xgboost-algorithm).
- increase `max_bin` or `max_bin_by_feature` when creating dataset

LightGBM training buckets continuous features into discrete bins to improve training speed and reduce memory requirements for training. This binning is done one time during Dataset construction. Increasing the number of bins per feature can increase the number of splits that can be made.

`max_bin` controls the maximum number of bins that features will bucketed into. It is also possible to set this maximum feature-by-feature, by passing `max_bin_by_feature`.

Answer (score 3):

set 'verbosity': -1 in params, it works!

Comment: I believe the question is about addressing the underlying issue, not just not seeing the warning printed.

Answer (score -1):

Increase `max_depth` or set it to `-1`.